# querying whether a font feature has been activated via a fontspec command

Tags: luatex, conditionals, fontspec, programming, opentype

A LaTeX package I'm currently writing makes use of -- and definitely requires -- some of the power of LuaLaTeX. I would like to make my package's user interface -- in particular, the options that need to be loaded -- as simple as possible by making the package determine on its own which "font features" have been activated via commands such as `\fontspec`, `\setmainfont`, `\defaultfontfeatures`, and `\addfontfeatures` that are provided by the `fontspec` package.

The font features I'm most interested in are ligatures, in particular those called "Common" (activated by `+liga`), "Required" (`+rlig`), "Contextual" (`+clig`), "Historic" (`+hlig`), and "Discretionary"/"Rare" (`+dlig`).

Some functionality of the type I'm looking for is mentioned in section 25.3 of the user guide (named "Programmer's interface) of the `fontspec` manual. However, no specific examples are provided to demonstrate how the macros listed in this section might be used in practice. Moreover, I must confess, I'm not at all familiar with LaTeX3, the LaTeX dialect used by the `fontspec` package. Thus, I'm in no position to construct a user macro of this type on my own.

*My question thus is*: How would one write a Boolean test -- likely based on a macro that uses the interface noted in section 25.3 of the `fontspec` manual -- to query if, say, "historic" ligatures have been activated via one of the methods provided by the `fontspec` package?

Comment: You're probably looking for `\fontspec_if_feature:nTF {rawfeature}{true}{false}` which could be `\let` to a more convenient name: `\ExplSyntaxOn \cs_new_eq:NN \testforfeature \fontspec_if_feature:nTF \ExplSyntaxOff`. This could then be used like `feauture hlig is \testforfeature{hlig}{active}{inactive}`

Comment: @cgnieder You should make this into an answer.

Comment: @egreg After reading the manual again I'm not so sure. It says about `\fontspec_if_feature:nTF`: “Test whether the currently selected font _contains_ the raw OpenType feature `#1`.” So the test is apparently not for _active_ features but for existent ones.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

First of all: there might be better ways to do this. Or at least other recommended ways...

It appears that `fontspec` updates what it calls a “sclist” with the activated raw features. A sclist is a list separated with a semicolon which means it is basically a token list. The idea would now be to look if a given raw feature is stored in that token list or not. The list containing the raw features appears to be `\l_fontspec_rawfeatures_sclist`. One can now test with `\tl_if_in:NnTF <tokenlistmacro> { tokens } { true } { false }` if a given feature is active.

`\cs_new:Npn` basically is a wrapper for `\long\def` and `\cs_new_eq:NN` basically is `\let`. The arg spec `nTF` means that the macro has three arguments, the `n` being a group of tokens given in braces. `T` and `F` also are arguments given in braces and are expanded if the test is either true or false, respectively.

```
\ExplSyntaxOn
% test if active font has feature:
\cs_new_eq:NN \IfFontFeatureExists \fontspec_if_feature:nTF
% test if feature is active:
\cs_new:Npn \mico_fontfeature_if_active:nTF #1
  { \tl_if_in:NnTF \l_fontspec_rawfeatures_sclist { #1 } }
\cs_new_eq:NN \IfFontFeatureActive \mico_fontfeature_if_active:nTF
\ExplSyntaxOff
```

A whole MWE could now look as follows:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont[Numbers=OldStyle]{LinLibertineO}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\cs_new_eq:NN \IfFontFeatureExists \fontspec_if_feature:nTF
\cs_new:Npn \mico_fontfeature_if_active:nTF #1
  { \tl_if_in:NnTF \l_fontspec_rawfeatures_sclist { #1 } }
\cs_new_eq:NN \IfFontFeatureActive \mico_fontfeature_if_active:nTF
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

liga \IfFontFeatureExists{liga}{exists}{does not exist},
clig \IfFontFeatureExists{clig}{exists}{does not exist},
rlig \IfFontFeatureExists{rlig}{exists}{does not exist},
hlig \IfFontFeatureExists{hlig}{exists}{does not exist},
dlig \IfFontFeatureExists{dlig}{exists}{does not exist}

liga is \IfFontFeatureActive{liga}{}{not} active,
hlig is \IfFontFeatureActive{hlig}{}{not} active,
dlig is \IfFontFeatureActive{dlig}{}{not} active

\addfontfeatures{Ligatures={Common,Historic}}
liga is \IfFontFeatureActive{liga}{}{not} active,
hlig is \IfFontFeatureActive{hlig}{}{not} active,
dlig is \IfFontFeatureActive{dlig}{}{not} active

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Any idea why \IfFontFeaturesActive doesn't work right for pnum, tnum, onum, lnum ?

Comment: @user22108 No... actually I don't know too much about the innards of `fontspec`. Maybe you should ask the `fontspec` maintainer. He should be able to give some insights

Comment: I hate to have to bother you about this, but your MWE has stopped working. :-( In particular, the `\l_fontspec_rawfeatures_sclist` macro appears to no longer exist in version 2.5a (dated 2016/02/01) of `fontspec`.  `fontspec` now provides a somewhat similarly named macro, viz., `\l_@@_rawfeatures_sclist`. Unfortunately, just replacing the one macro name doesn't restore the MWE to proper working order. May I ask you to look into what may be going on and, hopefullly, get your code to work once more? Thanks so much in advance!

Comment: @Mico I'll check this in a few hours. If `fontspec` actually has a `@@` macro then this may be an unintended bug. During the build process “`@@`”  should be replaced by “`fontspec`”.

Comment: @clemens - Thanks! I look forward to learning what you may be able find out.

Comment: @Mico it is now called `\l__fontspec_rawfeatures_sclist` (two underscores after the `\l`). This means it is no longer a public variable but now is an internal variable. IMHO this is unfortunate: you should have been able to rely on a public variable. You definitely can't rely on an internal one. It maybe worth asking Will for a public interface.

Comment: Thanks so much for looking into this issue in greater depth. I think I'll take you up on your suggestion.

Comment: @clemens - I've contacted Will Robertson per use suggestion, and got an encouraging reply: the double-underscore macro name, `\l__fontspec_rawfeatures_sclist`, may be used safely for the time being. (He added that the likelihood that the internal macro name would change again wasn't high.) He further said he'd look into providing a public interface to the internal macro; however, any such change will take longer to implement.

Comment: @Mico IMHO the best solution both for you and for Will would be a public function `\fontspec_if_feature_active:nTF`.

Comment: I fully agree. :-)