# \IfFontFeatureActive not working

Tags: fontspec

In an answer to [querying whether a font feature has been activated via a fontspec command](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/82292/2693) there are definitions of `\IfFontFeatureExists` and `\IfFontFeatureActive`.  I'm not getting reliable results for the second of these. For example, the following says that `pnum` is active and `tnum` is inactive, which are clearly not the case.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[osf,tabular]{libertineRoman}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\cs_new_eq:NN \IfFontFeatureExists \fontspec_if_feature:nTF
\cs_new:Npn \mico_fontfeature_if_active:nTF #1
  { \tl_if_in:NnTF \l_fontspec_rawfeatures_sclist { #1 } }
\cs_new_eq:NN \IfFontFeatureActive \mico_fontfeature_if_active:nTF
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

pnum \IfFontFeatureExists{pnum}{exists}{does not exist},
onum \IfFontFeatureExists{onum}{exists}{does not exist},
lnum \IfFontFeatureExists{lnum}{exists}{does not exist},
tnum \IfFontFeatureExists{tnum}{exists}{does not exist},

pnum is \IfFontFeatureActive{pnum}{}{not} active,
onum is \IfFontFeatureActive{onum}{}{not} active,
lnum is \IfFontFeatureActive{lnum}{}{not} active,
tnum is \IfFontFeatureActive{tnum}{}{not} active,

1234567890

\end{document}
```

Comment: It seems that, for some reasons, `tnum` is never added to `\l_fontspec_rawfeatures_sclist` with XeLaTeX. It is if LuaLaTeX is used. I'd classify this as a bug in `fontspec`.

Comment: tnum is added when it should be pnum and vice versa. That's for Libertine.  For BerenisADF, the active features are always tnum and lnum, no matter what.  I'd say this "feature" is seriously broken.

Comment: If it's a bug in fontspec, where/how do I report it?

Comment: This is the site for fontspec: https://github.com/wspr/fontspec/