# How do I enable a font feature?

Tags: fonts, fontspec, ligatures

I am trying to enable the Historical Ligatures feature in EB Garamond. The guide to the font calls this feature `hlig`. However, I have no idea how to enable the feature.

I found a question that seems to be related: [querying whether a font feature has been activated via a fontspec command](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/82292/querying-whether-a-font-feature-has-been-activated-via-a-fontspec-command). It mentions an `\addfontfeatures` command, but when I try `\addfontfeatures{hlig}`, I get an error: "The key 'fontspec/hlig' is unknown and is being ignored."

I haven't been able to find any concrete source about how I enable features. I feel like I'm missing something rather important.

Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{ebgaramond}
\addfontfeatures{Ligatures=Historic}

\begin{document}

These words should have ligatures: standard, acta, select.

\end{document}
```

Comment: `fontspec` doesn't use the feature codes directly, it has its own names for them. For `hlig`, you should use `\addfontfeatures{Ligatures=Historic}`. The complete list is found in the [package documentation](http://www.texdoc.net/pkg/fontspec). If, for some reason, you need to use the feature codes directly, you can set them using the `RawFeature` key, like this: `\addfontfeatures{RawFeature=+hlig}`.

Comment: @Paul Gessler: However, this doesn't produce the ` st` ligature, which `otfinfo` mentions.

Comment: @PaulGessler: I tried `\addfontfeatures{Ligatures=Historic}` and `\addfontfeatures{RawFeature=+hlig}`; neither worked, but at least they didn't throw an error.

Comment: @Soma we really need a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that/3225#3225) in order to help. That command might not be the way to go, depending on how you are loading the font and if you want to use the ligatures in the entire document or only locally. I only posted those examples because you asked about the `\addfontfeatures` macro.

Comment: @PaulGessler I added my source.

Comment: Please don't abuse the (short-s) `st` ligature by using it at the *start* of a word!

Comment: @jon I realize that's not the most attractive way to use; I just needed an example. Now that you brought it up, though, can I make LaTeX only do ligatures in the middle of a word?

Comment: Presumably with `s{}t`. A more sophisticated approach using Lua is possible with the `selnolig` package has a command `\nolig` that you could use; but you must use LuaLaTeX.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The `ebgaramond` package does not currently have an option to enable the historic ligatures feature. This would be the preferred way to select the ligatures.

Using `\addfontfeatures` in the preamble does not work, because it applies only to the font of the current group. So instead I place the `\addfontfeatures` command inside `\AtBeginDocument`, so it takes effect as soon as the document begins:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{ebgaramond}
\AtBeginDocument{\addfontfeatures{Ligatures=Historic}}

\begin{document}

These words should have ligatures: standard, acta, select.

\end{document}
```

[image]

This only works with Xe/LuaLaTeX. The converted versions of the fonts included in the package for pdfLaTeX do not have access to these ligatures.